# Video textures in GLTF/GLB export

Tags: video, gltf

been searching the web for a couple hours.
all I can find is that GLTB/GLB supports video textures and so do most of the sdks that support it.

BUT I cant find a way to export this out of blender, maybe there is a way to export without and then use an external tool to add the video texture, but im not sure about how to do that.

would be awesome if there was a branch of the gltf exporter\importer addon that supported video textures, if not the main plug in itself!!

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/MozillaReality/hubs-blender-exporter not sure it will help you but it might guide you to the right place

Comment: Currently no, core glTF/GLB does not include video texture support.  It could be added by means of an extension, but most existing tools don't support any such extension currently.

Comment: @ebi , thanks for this I'll check it out.

Comment: @emackey from what I have read and found it is a supported feature, maybe your right and it's not a core feature. But from what I can tell some sites do support it.